# http.get vs http.request in Angular

Tags: angular

I noticed people use 2 ways of retrieving data from remote source: `http.get()` and `http.request()`.

What is the difference between `http.get()` and `http.request()` method in Angular?

Comment: I'm downvoting this as not showing research effort, since this is easily found in the documentation:  https://angular.io/api/http/Http#request

Comment: i'm sorry. Google was clueless. In general, it doenst link to the angular docs. Perhaps this qquestion will help future readers,
 since it ranks well. (https://www.google.com/search?q=http.get+vs+http.request+angular)

Comment: When you search for any Angular (2-4) docs or tips on Google, I strongly recommend adding `-angularjs` after your search terms in order to clean the results of all the non-relevant AngularJS bloating! otherwise it can be a pain to find what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`http.get()` is just **a shorthand** to using `http.request()` with the `method` field of the `Request` argument set as `RequestMethod.Get` .

The same goes for the `http` methods named with a HTTP verb :

- `http.put()`
- `http.post()`
- `http.delete()`
- `http.head()`
- `http.patch()`
- `http.options()`

(with, depending on the method, some convenient other arguments as shortcut for the relevant `RequestOption`, such as `body` for `http.post()` )

So the actual only difference is *just readability*, but that's IMHO important enough to prefer these specific methods over directly using `http.request()`

For information, here is the relevant documentation link : https://angular.io/api/http/Http#members , a good place to start for any basic question on the meaning and syntax of the common Angular objects and methods.

Also, don't forget that Angular is Open Source, you can just search for any code of the various packages, and have a look at it!

Here is the source for http : https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/http.ts .